# Below code not working.whats wrong. First time using jQuery, Checked in Firefox and IE

Tags: jquery

Below is the simple code to alert a message using jQuery

I faced this issue long back also but I tried to continue with JavaScript itself but now trying to learn jQuery Form Validation Plugin. However jQuery itself not working for me.Kindly assist

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <title>Form Validation</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "Form.css" />
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(fuction(){
$("#submit").on("click",function(){
alert("Hello");
});
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form">
<input type="email"  />
<input type="Submit" id="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to prevent the default event (which is submission of the form, in this case, because the type of input is `submit`). Or, turn the type of that button into `button`

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your script, there's an n missing in function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").on("click",function(){
    alert("Hello");
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ArcaneCraeda/79sLtqwe/1/)

If you want to prevent the form submission:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Hello");
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ArcaneCraeda/79sLtqwe/2/)

Comment: Hi JS Fiddle works. Tried preventing form submission as above but it still not working in local

Comment: Hmm, well you could do as Derek mentioned above and turn the button into a type `button`. Is the prevention not working, as in, the form is still being submitted?

Comment: What's your browser/OS setup? Cause if it stories on fiddle it should work universally.

Comment: Firefox 43.0.4 and Windows 7 Home Basic SP1

Comment: Awesome. Can you set this question as resolved by accepting either my or Shriya's answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <title>Form Validation</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "Form.css" />
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#submit").on("click",function(){
               alert("Hello");
            });
     });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form">
<input type="email"  />
<input type="Submit" id="submit" />
</form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: @Lambo spelling mistake in your code "$(document).ready(fuction(){" . Replace fuction with function.

Comment: Where ? I can't figure it out

Comment: My code works fine in JS Fiddle but its not working fine in my local Firefox,IE browser

Comment: I don't c any difference to your code and mine. Where u made the changes copy that line and paste

Comment: OMG thanks alot. Grrrrrrr How I forgot to check wasted alot of time thanks

Comment: Yeah thanks alot.I can't vote it because I have low reputation